# Oracle Forms 10g LOV not showing up second time

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I have created Oracle Forms 10g form and want to display LOV by pressing the button. On When-Button-Pressed trigger I have:

```
go_item('MyBlock.Item1');
do_key('LIST_VALUES');
```

LOV has 6 columns and 2 of them are bound to 2 items: MyBlock.Item1 and MyBlock.Item2. When I press the button LOV appears and I can make a choice. LOV inserts data into MyBlock.Item1 and MyBlock.Item2 and everything is fine.
But if I want to make another choice and press the button again LOV doesn't appear. I don't know what is the problem.

Button and both items are in the same data block, I set Update Allowed and Required to No for both items and Mouse Navigate to No for button (I saw this on few forums).

Comment: Have you tried with show_lov?

Comment: @pablomatico Thanks. Yes, I have tried with `a_value_chosen := Show_Lov('MY_LOV'); 
   IF a_value_chosen THEN ...` but second time a_value_chosen is not true neither false, it's null.

Comment: are you sure your current item is myblock.item1 when you call show_lov?

Comment: Yes because I add `message('SYSTEM.CURSOR_ITEM = ' || :SYSTEM.CURSOR_ITEM);` just before `a_value_chosen := Show_Lov('MY_LOV');` and get that it is MyBlock.Item1.

Comment: is there any difference the second time you try to show the lov? has the data involved in the query changed? if you add a message just after the show_lov, is it showed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution (using oracle's OTN discussion).
The problem was stored procedure I call after first popping up of LOV. First time, after I chose a value I delete record of another block using stored procedure. In that procedure I set values of columns MyBlock.Item1 and MyBlock.Item2 are connected with. But on the form the old values remains on items. I removed update this two columns in procedure and it works now. But I needed this two fields to be updated to null automatically.

The solution is that I first change values of those items on form and then I call stored procedure. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting synchronize command between these two lines:

```
go_item('MyBlock.Item1');
Synchronize;
do_key('LIST_VALUES');
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but it didn't work. The same thing.

Comment: Ok it does not shows the lov, but is cursor there ? or the cursor is on the other item.

Comment: Cursor is on the another Data Block and item because code inserts new record on other Data Block. Maybe this makes a problem?

Comment: Another data block is not the problem, but cursor should be on that item for which you are calling list_values, if cursor is not there then it will not show the lov.

Comment: Isn't the line _go_item('MyBlock.Item1');_ for that purpose? However I put that line after deleting details record and it is blue when I try to popup LOV second time and it's the same.